# Increase WooCommerce tax calculations precision and keep displayed prices with two decimals

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, tax

In Woocommerce settings, I have set 6 decimals in order to get more accurate tax calculation. However, I need all prices and amounts to be displayed with only 2 decimals in frontend, emails etc. I found two functions

```
add_filter('wc_price_args', 'custom_decimals_price_args', 10, 1);
function custom_decimals_price_args($args) {
$args['decimals'] = 2;
return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wc_get_price_decimals', 'change_prices_decimals', 20, 1 );
function change_prices_decimals( $decimals ){
$decimals = 2;
return $decimals;
}
```

What is the difference between these and which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION` constant is set to **`6`** in [`WC_Woocommerce` define_constants() method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-woocommerce.php#L241).

That means that **WooCommerce Tax calculation precision is already set on 6 decimals.**

Tax calculation **precision** are based on [`wc_get_rounding_precision()` core function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1844-L1857) used in [`WC_Tax` Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-wc-tax.php#L37):

```
function wc_get_rounding_precision() {
    $precision = wc_get_price_decimals() + 2;
    if ( absint( WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION ) > $precision ) {
        $precision = absint( WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION );
    }
    return $precision;
}
```

As you can see `WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION` constant is prioritized if the **displayed price decimal value + 2** is smaller than `WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION` constant. But as you want to keep **displayed** prices with 2 decimals, this requires something else.

> So you should not increase displayed price decimals and not use `wc_price_args` or/and `wc_get_price_decimals` hooks, to increase precision in tax calculation.

If **precision of 6 decimals is not enough** and you want to get more precision:

#### How to get more precision on Tax calculations?

The best way to get more precision on tax calculations and keep displayed prices with 2 decimals is to edit WordPress wp_config.php file and add the following lines *(where you can increase `WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION` constant value as you like, here the value is set to **8** for example)*:

```
// Change WooCommerce rounding precision
define('WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION', 8);
```

This will change `WC_ROUNDING_PRECISION` constant without affecting displayed price decimals.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that Woocommerce is using 6 decimals for calculations. So that means that even if you set it to 2 in the backends settings you can still enter 6 decimals for product prices?

Comment: @fredrik This is about rounding precision in calculations and specifically in your case for tax calculations… If frontend **displayed** prices is set to 2 decimals, you can set your prices just as you want in the backend (with the number of decimals that you want). Real real prices that are set in the backend and formatted displayed prices on the frontend are something different.

Answer (score 0):

`wc_price_args` is used to add extra arguments to the price - it takes in raw price and it can add other stuff to it like for example a currency symbol. When `get_price` is called it will include this currency symbol in the front end.
https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/wc_price_args

`wc_get_price_decimals` it sets a number of decimals after the 'point' - eg. if you set it to 5, the price will look like 0.00000
https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/function/wc_get_price_decimals

I didn't test this but it should do the job.

```
add_filter('wc_price_args', 'custom_decimals_price_args', 10, 1);
function custom_decimals_price_args($price, $args) {
  
  return number_format((float)$price, 2, '.', '');

}
```

Alternatively, you can edit the template where your products are and format the `get_price` with the `number_format` above.

Let me know if this worked for you.