# Filter Item Unit Price when Order is Created in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, filter, orders

I'm using Zapier to export orders from WooCommerce to my account software when an order is created. The data is sent via WooCommerce REST API.

Everything works fine but I noticed that the unit price in the order meta data sometimes displays product prices with more than 2 decimal places. This happens when more than one of the same item is ordered. It seems to always happen when the item price has two decimal places and is ordered in multiples of odd numbers.

My accounting software only accepts up to 2 decimal places. So there is an error every time the unit price has more than two decimal places. This is how I discovered this issue.

I have checked the item price and the prices are correct. I also tested by enabling and disabling "Round tax at subtotal level, instead of rounding per line". Nothing seems to resolve the issue.

I would like to filter the unit price when an order is generated in WooCommerce so that they are converted to two decimal places. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to go about resolving this would be appreciated.

Here is an example of just one order where the item is displaying with more than 2 decimal places:

```
isCreditInvoice:false
customer:d58ca99b-07f3-45fa-80ae-164ebbc881f1
invoiceDate:2021-03-07T09:18:06+02:00
quantity:1,1,1,1,1,1,2,6,6,5,7,7,4,10,10,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
yourReference:Order Number 6631
deliveryDate:{{111079934__date_completed}}
ourReference:Order Number 6631
unitPrice:22.5,22.5,26.25,25,34.95,34.95,23.76,6.95,6.95,6.95,9.950000000000001,9.950000000000001,9.95,1.6,1.6,14.95,23.4,8.4,30,21.36,25,12.5,26.5
```

**Update: This is a WooCommerce Plugin Core issue and has already been reported to WooCommerce on Github**

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27911

Use the following patch to temporarily fix the issue:

Navigate to line 172 of woocommerce/includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version2/class-wc-rest-orders-v2-controller.php

Replace:

```
$data['price'] = $item->get_quantity() ? $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity() : 0;
```

With:

```
$data['price'] = $item->get_quantity() ? wc_format_decimal( $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity() ): 0;
```

Tested and works.

Now the unitPrice will be rounded to two decimal places.

Comment: I'm actually already speaking to people that work with WooCommerce. They believe it's a core issue and suggested that I create a thread on Github. They suggested I filter the prices when an order is created. This is the data that is being sent from WooCommerce to Zapier. So the data is being generated in WooCommerce in exactly this way.

Comment: Zapier have a feature that lets you filter prices (round to two decimal places). But it's a paid for feature. If I can fix the issue at the source then I won't need to filter the prices on Zapier.

Comment: Apparently it might also have to do with an issue in PHP with floating point precision: https://labs.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/?fbclid=IwAR3c3muOmoULpZxydg-YmuaLBV5R_L7sAeI-a19xkytaYkBcD23hAD9Cs1I

Comment: I see… Each plugin has its own way to get the data from wooCommerce, so you should try to find out how Zapier is doing that… This will allow you to better target where you need to make changes… Normally If it's a good plugin (well maid and open) you should try to find what hooks you could use.

Comment: Note that WooCommerce Limit the decimals precision to 6 digits…

Comment: Thanks. I'll check Github to see if I can find more info. I've also been told to isolate the filtering to the plugin so I don't cause penny rounding issues on my store. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Noted! Thank you!

Comment: Could I possibly use the solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424141/custom-decimals-in-woocommerce-product-prices-for-a-product-category) to set decimals to two decimals on the order admin page?

Comment: I looked through the plugin and it doesn't look like it's generating any metadata. It appears to pull metadata already generated by WooCommerce and sending the data as is to my accounting software. I'm updating the question to highlight the order metadata that Zapier extracts.

Comment: maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183179/increase-woocommerce-tax-calculations-precision-and-keep-displayed-prices-with-t/66186395#66186395

Comment: It worked. I set the precision to 8 and it's rounding to two decimal places. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry. It was a false alarm. I only ordered one item. If I order more than 1, then changing the precision didn't help. I noticed that there is no hook for "$unit_price" in WooCommerce. Can I assume that this is a Zapier plugin hook and that it is calculating this by taking the "$line_total" and dividing it by "$quantity"? And by doing so, they are increasing the number of decimals so that they get you to pay for the plan that lets you filter prices? I'll look through the plugin to see how they are calculating "$unit_price" and adjust the code accordingly...

Comment: I spoke to the plugin developer and they said they don't actually alter the data in WooCommerce. They rely on WooCommerce REST API to deliver data via WooCommerce webhooks. They suggested I look for a way to override the unit_price data field in the WooCommerce REST API orders object. So it seems to me that the round issue could be inherent in WooCommerce itself.

Comment: They should report themselves the bug to WooCommerce Github opening an issue.

Comment: Agreed. I'll report the issue myself. Thanks again for the guidance.

Comment: Did some more digging around and it seems I'm not the only one with this issue.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27911

Comment: It seems that there is a patch for this issue. One would need to change this:

"$data['price'] = $item->get_quantity() ? $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity() : 0;"

And replace it with this:

"$data['price'] = $item->get_quantity() ? wc_format_decimal( $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity() ): 0;"

Do you have any idea where in the WooCommerce plugin I can find this?

Comment: Never mind! I obviously cannot read. It's on line 172 in /woocommerce/includes/rest-api/Controllers/Version2/class-wc-rest-orders-v2-controller.php. I'll test it in staging.